# Отловить закрытие программы

Tags: python

Как отловить нажатие на крестик?
Нужно, чтобы при нажатие на крестик программа выполнила некоторые действия и закрылась

Comment: У формы есть событие onClose.

Comment: Можно пример, пожалуйста?

Comment: Зависит от того какую библиотеку вы используете для создания графического интерфейса.

Comment: Обычная консоль

Comment: т.е. вы хотите запустить `python test.py` в терминале и с ее помощью поймать закрытие терминала? Возможно вам это поможет https://pymotw.com/2/atexit/

Comment: Попробовал пример, который там. 
Не получилось(
Если это Вас не затруднит, то можете попробовать сами и скинуть мне свой вариант.